# Опечатка в окне закрытия: вЫписывался в тематику

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот здесь:**

> Хотите улучшить этот вопрос? Обновите вопрос так, чтобы он
> в**Ы**писывался в тематику Stack Overflow на русском.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Строкa](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14924)

Поправил перевод. В понедельник появится.